# Difference between ls -l /boot and ls -l /boot/

Tags: command-line

There was a command I found explaining the ls -l command, and it gave an example as `ls -l /boot/`. I find that `ls -l /boot` and `ls -l /boot/` have the same results. Does /boot and /boot/ have any differences? What does the / after boot (/boot **/**) mean in contrast to /boot without a / after boot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The slash after `boot` shows that it is a directory, not a file.

You can see the difference if you create `boot` file in your home directory. Run

```
touch boot
ls -l boot/
ls -l boot
```

and you'll see what I mean.

If `boot` is a directory, it doesn't make any difference to run either way.